# Helm Chart iteratively create pods , Containers , ports , service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have 4 Microservices they all have different names different images and different container ports and service ports, I took this piece of code in one of the answer from stack overflow now what this piece of code is doing is creating my 4 deployments with it's names and images but I am unable to create 4 container according to their ports and resources.
my main goal is to create a master template where I can just put few values and it can handle new manifest of new microservice instead of play with bunch of manifest separately.

```
deployment.yaml
```

```
{{ if .Values.componentTests }}
{{- range .Values.componentTests }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ . }}
  labels:
    environment: {{ $.Values.environment }}
    app: {{ . }}
    aadpodidbinding: podid-{{ . }}
    chart: {{ $.Chart.Name }}-{{ $.Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ $.Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ $.Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ $.Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ . }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ . }}
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
        - name: {{ . }}
          image: mycr.azurecr.io/master/{{ . }}:{{ $.Values.image.tag }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ $.Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          resources:
            {{- range $.Values.high.resources }}
---
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{ end }}
```

```
values.yaml
```

```
replicaCount: 1

image:
#   repository: nginx
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
#   # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: "latest"
componentTests:
   - service01
   - service02
   - service03
   - service04
environment: QA
imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
services:
   - service01
   - service02
   - service03
# serviceAccount:
#   # Specifies whether a service account should be created
#   create: true
#   # Annotations to add to the service account
#   annotations: {}
#   # The name of the service account to use.
#   # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
#   name: ""

podAnnotations: {}

podSecurityContext: {}
  # fsGroup: 2000

securityContext: {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 1000

# service:
#   type: ClusterIP
#   port: 80

# ingress:
#   enabled: false
#   annotations: {}
#     # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
#     # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
#   hosts:
#     - host: chart-example.local
#       paths: []
#   tls: []
#   #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
#   #    hosts:
#   #      - chart-example.local
high:
  resources: 
    requests:
      cpu: 350m
      memory: 800Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 400m
      memory: 850Mi
medium:
  resources: 
    requests:
      cpu: 200m
      memory: 650Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 250m
      memory: 700Mi
low:
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 500Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 150m
      memory: 550Mi

autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 4
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80

tolerations: []
affinity: {}
```

```
output

MANIFEST:
---
# Source: test/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service01
  labels:
    environment: QA
    app: service01
    aadpodidbinding: podid-service01
    chart: test-0.1.1
    release: api
    heritage: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service01
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service01
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
        - name: service01
          image: mycr.azurecr.io/master/service01:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
---
# Source: test/templates/deployment.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service02
  labels:
    environment: QA
    app: service02
    aadpodidbinding: podid-service02
    chart: test-0.1.1
    release: api
    heritage: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service02
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service02
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
        - name: service02
          image: mycr.azurecr.io/master/service02:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
---
# Source: test/templates/deployment.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service02-ui
  labels:
    environment: QA
    app: service02-ui
    aadpodidbinding: podid-service02-ui
    chart: test-0.1.1
    release: api
    heritage: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service02-ui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service02-ui
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
        - name: service02-ui
          image: mycr.azurecr.io/master/service02-ui:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
---
# Source: test/templates/deployment.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service03
  labels:
    environment: QA
    app: service03
    aadpodidbinding: podid-service03
    chart: test-0.1.1
    release: api
    heritage: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service03
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service03
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
        - name: service03
          image: mycr.azurecr.io/master/service03:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
---
# Source: test/templates/deployment.yaml
```

```
service01.yaml
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service01
  labels:
    aadpodidbinding: podid-service01
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service01
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service01
        aadpodidbinding: podid-service01
      annotations:
        build: "2020102901"
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: service01
        image: mycr.azurecr.io/master/service01:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: "700Mi"
          limits:
            memory: "700Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7474
        env:
        - name: KEY_VAULT_ID
          value: "key-vault"
        - name: AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME
          value: "storage"
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 7474
            scheme: HTTP
            httpHeaders:
            - name: service-id
              value: root
            - name: request-id
              value: healthcheck
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 30
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 7474
            scheme: HTTP
            httpHeaders:
            - name: service-id
              value: root
            - name: request-id
              value: healthcheck
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 30
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service01
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 7474
    name: main
#  - port: 9999
#    name: health
  selector:
    app: service01
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: service01
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: service01
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 4
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
```

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering?  You could create the matching Services with the same technique, even inside the same loop; just remember to put the YAML `---` start-of-document marker before each object declaration.

Comment: you are right here but see my output i have attached i want my service01 container to be on port 8080 and 8081 and service02 container should be on 7474 and 7171 i am unable to do that all three containers and different port i have no idea how to put together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know in what context that Helm chart was created, but from what I understand it was used for Integration testing or something like that. It is certainly not what you want to use for your use case. You better use an Helm Chart that generate the manifests for only one services and then you'll be able to reuse that Chart for all your services. It means that you will do multiple `helm install` with different values instead of one `helm install` that created all your services. With a big chart like that, you'll need to update the chart everytime you add a new services.

You'll have :

```
helm install -f service01-values.yaml ./mychart
helm install -f service02-values.yaml ./mychart
helm install -f service03-values.yaml ./mychart
helm install -f service04-values.yaml ./mychart
```

instead of :

```
helm install -f values.yaml ./mychart
```

To be able to do this, you'll need to change your chart a little bit and remove the loop `{{- range .Values.componentTests }}`. Learn how to build a chart, it is easyer that you think : [Create Your First Helm Chart](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/create-your-first-helm-chart/)

Comment: but i have 10 microservices they all have different container values , ports etc. if you could take a look at my manifest -service01.yaml this is one of them rest are little different i just want one deployment.yaml file where i configure all the pods and containers and it should auto create values accordingly instead have 10 service-values.yaml files,

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how Helm it is supposed to be used. The goal is to have one deployment file in your Helm chart and then pass the values according to the service you want to deploy... service-values.yaml files only contains the values that differ between services. It can be command parameters if you prefer. Helm is not meant to deploy everything with one helm install, it is a template that you reuse with different values. If you don't want to reuse the template, maybe you should look at something like https://kustomize.io/ to deploy everything with one command.